# using the value of one element to find another in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a selectbox in a project. It is part of a form. With the menu a product is selected. On the same line is an input where the price of the product must come. Somewhere hidden in the page I have a div which is ID'd with the name of the product. This div contains the product data (price and some other data). I have an eventhandler in place, which reacts to the selectbox (javascript on(change)).

In the eventhandler I have the following code to find the div containing the price (prijs, I'm Dutch). It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$(this).parent('tr').find('#prijs').val($(div).find($this.val()).find('#prijs')).val();
```

I fixed all the stupid typos I made. Thanks for getting those out. Thursdaynight crunch time got me going south a bit. I will give a more elaborate example below.

```
   <select name='producten[1]' class='product'>
     <option value='phone1'>phone1</option>
     <option value='phone1'>phone2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="prijs"></input>
    <input type="text" id="per"></input>


    <div class="hidden" id="phone1"><div id="dbprijs">'125.00'</div><div id="dbper">a piece</div></div>
    <div class="hidden" id="phone2"><div id="dbprijs">225.00</div><div id="dbper">a piece</div></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function(){
                        $("body").on("change",".product", function(){

                              $(this).parent('tr').find('#prijs').val($('div').find($(this).val()).find('#dbprijs')).val();
                        });
        }
    );
   </script>
```

[A JSFiddle with the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/jveen4/Aw3Py/)

As far as I can see the real challenge here is tell JQuery to look for an id with the value of the selectbox. Thanks to Fabrizio for editing the original question.

Comment: Could you please post HTML code

Comment: Note that there must only be one element on the page with the id "prijs". If you've got more than one, things won't work properly.

Comment: Try to change val($(div) to val($('div')

Comment: Can you possibly make a quick [jsFiddle](www.jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the entire project?

Answer (score 2):

One possible error is `this` not being wrapped in `$()`
Second that `div` is without single quotes.

```
$(this).parent('tr').find('#prijs').val($('div').find($(this).val()).find('#prijs')).val();
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it becomes difficult to use the `.on`. So please try to use `.change` instead of that as below mentioned code.

**`jQuery("select.product").change( function(){
    /* Now your code */
});`**

Except that you need to be sure that how you would get that `tr`. As you mentioned into the html, that needs to be inside the `select` field's parent element.

Hope this will clear the approach! Cheers!